# PHP DOMPDF issue => text goes out of table margin

Tags: php, css, dompdf

PHP DOMPDF issue
I making a script which convert HTML table into PDF. But for some reason the text usually goes out of the margin. I already tried margin set in CSS withou results. I already sent an email to dompdf responsible without any answer.
Can any one help me?
Regards

Comment: Could you show sample code please? The DOMPDF Google Groups is made for this kind of questions. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/dompdf

Comment: I fixed the problem downloading new version 6 beta 3. Thanks!!